# How to async run vimscript system calls

Tags: vimscript, async

I have a vimscript function which uses a combination of vimscript functions and also some calls to `:call system()`. The vimscript and the `system()` calls can be 5-10 seconds slow, during which time, Vim is frozen. How do I defer the entire script to another thread? I read online that `timer_start()` should work, but it doesn't for me.

I tried this:

```
function! SlowCall()
    let text = system('sleep 3 ; ls')  " An example of a slow system call + some return value
    echo text
    " ... imagine more vimscript functions that use `text`, below ...
endfunction

call timer_start(0, { -> SlowCall() })
```

If I source the above script, Vim prevents typing for 3 seconds, instead of running in the background while I continue to work. How do I run `SlowCall()` in the background without interrupting typing?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read through that prior to posting but unfortunately it didn't give me the result I needed.


> If you remove that and just have ls does it change anything?


It's a bit hard to tell since ls returns results so quickly. If I replace the sleep + ls with find / -name "foo", it still hangs though. So probably it's not an issue specific to `sleep`

Comment: Okay. (Kudos for reading that beforehand.) So `system()` itself? I'll try it when I'm able.

Comment: Of course, you can't just run `system()` or any other arbitrary VimScript function and expect it to run asynchronously. There's a dedicated API for running external processes. See `:h job`. Note that API is incompatible across Vim / Neovim. There are some "compat plugins" but you only need'em if you target both editors and/or find Job API too difficult to use as is.

Comment: I believe Vimscript does not support multiple threads. It can not do async. `timer_start` is not really async stuff, instead, it allows to schedule execution of some Vimscript to a later time (or to run several times/in loops). But the `SlowCall` function will occupy the "Vimscript thread".

The only solution, as far as I know, is to rely on external threads in other languages (e.g. Python). For this, the `job` backend is useful, see `:help job-start`.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Oh, fiddlesticks. I was under the impression that there was limited multi-threading (for things like `timer_start()`) but I think you're right. Single-threaded through and through. I've got a couple answers to edit. :P

Comment: @BLayer yeah, the `job` API is the parallel API (well, parallel from the users perspective; it's still an OS level job, which might "only" be concurrent). Timers are concurrent but single-threaded (aka not parallel, but maybe qualify as asynchronous (if you use the definitions that I seem to see most often)).

Comment: Since job_start only runs shell commands from what I can see, I guess that means my only options are to either 1. Refactor all of the code to be a shell script or 2. Maybe have job_start call vim and use it to execute my function. I tried using the close_cb callback, for example, to not have to do that but it still prevents typing. If there's an easier way than 1 or 2, please let me know.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah this doesn't change the fact that timers are async, IMO. The fact that they don't fire immediately (they don't even fire after a fixed time necessarily...the time param is a minimum) is all that is required. Concurrent and non-parallel...yes.

Comment: @ColinKennedy where did you get the idea that job_start runs shell commands? Any program you can run it can run (though I don’t remember off the top of my head whether it’s exec-like or sh-c-like in how it invokes those programs). (Also, a program name is a valid shell command—that’s a shell’s main purpose, to run other programs.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was more trying to say "I don't see a way to use job_start to run a Vim function, async" which is a problem in my case, because what I was trying to make async combines vimscript + `system()` calls. So my choices now, I think, are to either A. Port it entirely to a shell command and run job_start B. in job_start, re-run vim with a start-up Vim function call C. Forgo job_start and use a higher-order language that has async support, like Python, to defer execution. Please let me know if there are other options I can try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple mockup using `job_start()`; note that in general many things which are straightforward in single-threaded vim (*e.g.*, modify the current buffer) are more complicated when dealing with asynchronous callbacks (*e.g.*, the current buffer may have changed). There are lots of options, so here I'm using `:help read-in-close-cb`.

```
function HandleText(channel) abort
  let text = []
  while ch_status(a:channel, {'part': 'out'}) == 'buffered'
    let text += [ch_read(a:channel)]
  endwhile
  let text = join(text, '\n')
  " … imagine more vimscript functions that use `text`, below …
endfunction

let job = job_start(['sh', '-c', 'sleep 5; exec ls'], #{close_cb: 'HandleText'})
```

With `callback` or a combination of `out_cb` and `err_cb`, you can handle lines of output as they are returned; this is useful if the job steadily produces information you want to process. The `sleep 5; ls` is more of a job that "can take some time and [we] don't need intermediate results" (`:help read-in-close-cb`).